# Вывести определенные поля из базы данных

Tags: mysql, база-данных

Вот такой вопрос, необходимо вывести определенные поля из таблицы базы данных MySQL. Нужно чтобы поля выводились в файл(txt, xls) с простой структурой вида:
(пример)

```
имя:телефон
Василий:111
Евгений:222
...........
```

Может посоветуете какую нибудь прогу для удобной работы с таблицами, чтоб можно было настроить вывод полей? Желательно чтобы была возможность сразу записать измененные значения в таблицу базы данных.

Comment: Какой язык программирования используете?

Comment: База данных MySql, сайт на вордпресс, язык пусть будет php.

Comment: `SELECT ...
INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':'
ENCLOSED BY ''
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вам надо написать ваш запрос полностью и только потом добавить про вывод в csv

```
SELECT <что>  from <откуда> where <и другие условия>
  INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv' 
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' 
    ENCLOSED BY '' 
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

1. SELECT `phones` FROM `users`;
2. обработать результаты с помощью ЯП.

PS. Если нужен какой-то пример, то могу написать, но только чуть позже

Comment: Можможно обойтись без ЯП? Нужно что нить типа phpMyAdmin, но попроще, понагляднее. Или какой запрос в phpMyAdmin сделать чтобы значения строк вывелись без всяких кавычек и скобок?

Comment: @skit008 вы мой комментарий видели?

Comment: Да видел, поставил вместо ... поля, все что после "file.csv" выдает ошибки. А если все что после убрать пишет "доступ закрыт для пользователя....."

Comment: Что вы набирали и как? Просто код, который привел Splash58 действителен и должен работать на ура (по факту не тестировал, но мое мнение что этот код должен работать)...

Comment: @skit008, оформите ваш комментарий в качестве ответа и я за него проголосую

Answer (score 0):

Набирал в phpMyAdmin

```
SELECT `post_title`,`post_content` INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Вот ответ

```
Найдено 11 ошибок при анализе.

Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "FIELDS" at position 63)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "TERMINATED" at position 70)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "BY" at position 81)
Неожиданный токен. (near "':'" at position 84)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "ENCLOSED" at position 88)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "BY" at position 97)
Неожиданный токен. (near "''" at position 100)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "LINES" at position 103)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "TERMINATED" at position 109)
Неизвестное ключевое слово. (near "BY" at position 120)
Неожиданный токен. (near "'\n'" at position 123)
```

SQL запрос

```
SELECT `post_title`,`post_content` INTO OUTFILE 'filename.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ':' ENCLOSED BY '' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

Ответ MySQL

#1045 - Доступ закрыт для пользователя '*****'@'localhost' (был использован пароль: ДА)
```